# Find data from datafram with several index in python

Tags: python, numpy, pyomo

I need to read data from datafram with several index(year, mounth , day , hour), how can i code this issue in  python. for example I want find data for fist mounth first day first hour temperature data for 2010 and then sum it with same data in 2011.

```
                    temperature
```

year mounth day hour

2010   1   1     1          30
.   .     .          31
1     24         32
.   2
.   .                .
1   31
.
.                   .
12  31    24         32
.
.
.
2022

I try to calculate avarage tempereture for 10 years through historical data, data is on excel  and i can read data with several indexes(year , mounth , day , hour) on dataframe in pythone, then i can find the same hourly data for 10 years and then sum them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.